# Fixing GoogleMonkeyR column width issue. How to change a script's CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, greasemonkey

[GoogleMonkeyR](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/9310) is an awesome Greasemonkey script, however it is currently a bit broken, as the search results come across in a very narrow column.

Running:

```
document.getElementById("GoogleTabledResults").style="width:1900px";
```

In the console widens them out like they should be but I can't figure out how to apply that to either GoogleMonkeyR or a script of its own. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `document.getElementById()` is probably running before that node actually exists.  Don't set styles that way as a rule.  Use Cascading Style Sheets (CSS).  The style can be preloaded and waiting for whenever a matching element shows up.

Just edit the script to add this line at the very end:

```
GM_addStyle ( "#GoogleTabledResults { width: 1900px !important; }" );
```

---

---

You can edit the live/installed copy of the script using one Greasemonkey's "Manage Userscripts Menus" (right-click to get the edit command).

Alternatively, you can:

1. Save the script to your system (not in a temp folder, though).
2. Edit that copy.
3. Uninstall the current script, this is important.
4. Then, install your local copy.
5. [Report the issue to the script's developer](http://userscripts.org/scripts/discuss/9310).

Comment: Ah I love you, I can finally use Google properly!